# Format for JSON files for Intents and Entities on API.AI

Tags: json, voice-recognition, dialogflow-es, google-home

I am looking for good explanation of what the general format is for creating an JSON file for an intent or entity. I see that the option is available for uploading JSON files for the intents and entities. I am looking for a format that I can use and fill out in order to create my own intents through JSON rather than individually through the Web client. Any advice or tips would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here lists what are on the intent JSON files https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/intents In addition, you can just take a look at some of intents of your own, download it, and use it as a template.

Comment: Thank you for your help!